# Converting a number to feet & inches

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to take a number from a table ( using sql server 2008 ) such as 720 and convert it to feet and inches  with this:

```
Format(Val(Length) \ 12, "00' ") & Format(Val(Length) Mod 12, "00\""")
```

This should be in a sql statement.

I'm having trouble getting the syntax correct. Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can use `format()` for this, it is not necessary.

When creating strings with a particular format, I like to use `replace()` with wildcards in the string.  This lets me easily control the format to see what is being produced:

```
select replace(replace('<feet>'' <inches>"',
                       '<feet>', val(length) / 12),
               '<inches>', val(length) % 12)
```

This assumes that the expression `val(length)` returns an integer.  If the column is just called length, then you would use `length` instead of `val(length)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```
DECLARE @value INT = 720
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@value /12) + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@value %12)+'"'
```