# SQL Real number convert to Ft & In

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

`enter code here`I asked a question back in May about how to convert a number from a table that inches, such as 300.9 to a Ft' In" display. I got two very good answers...

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),finlength /12) + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),finlength %12)+'"' as FinishLen

replace(replace('<feet>'' <inches>', '<feet>', FinLength / 12), '<inches>', FinLength % 12) as FinishLen
```

Both worked well until I ran into a table that the inches are declared as "REAL" numbers. Now I ran into this error...

"The data types real and int are incompatible in the modulo operator."

How can I display that? I can't change the table declarations. Other users need that data as well.

Thanks  and Kuddos for the great site.

Guess the full query might help, sorry.

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 ProdWkYr
          ,Product
          ,Grade
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),finlength /12) + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),finlength %12)+'"' as FinishLen
          ,BlmWeight
          ,BlmsNeeded
          ,BlmFootWgt
      FROM NYS2MiscOrderInfo
      where ProdWkYr = 3215

  order by product, Grade
```

Comment: Can you show a link to your previous question?

Comment: Can you supply some sample data hat leads to your error message?

Comment: Previous question--[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078773/converting-a-number-to-feet-inches]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include a `floor()` in your expression like

```
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------
-- set-up some test data using a CTE:
WITH tst as ( SELECT 13.7 finlength UNION ALL SELECT 123 )
-- alternatively: generate a table [tst] with a single column [finlength] 
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),FLOOR(finlength / 12)) + '''' 
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),finlength % 12)+'"' as FinishLen
FROM tst

-- results:
FinishLen
1'1.70"
10'3."
```

This will turn the first (ft) value into an integer while the second one (in) will still show all the digits after the decimal point.

**UPDATE**

When I ran the select from a #tmp table I got the same error as OP. I then modified and ended up with this:

It is as ugly as hell now, but at least **it works now**, see here [SQL Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353414/foot-inch):

```
create table #tst (finlength float);
INSERT INTO #tst VALUES (13.7),(123.),(300.9);

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),FLOOR(finlength / 12)) + '''' -- ft
      +CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),finlength-FLOOR(finlength)    -- in: fractional part
      +CAST(FLOOR(finlength) as int) %12)+'"'            -- in: integer part
as FinishLen 
FROM #tst
```

**Please note:** The formula will return reasonable results for positive values. For "negative distances" further changes are necessary. If similar output is required in different places then a UDF makes sense here. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ftinstr(@v float) RETURNS varchar(32) BEGIN
 DECLARE @l int;
 SELECT @l=FLOOR(ABS(@v));
 RETURN CAST(SIGN(@v)*(@l/12) AS varchar(6))+''''
       +CAST( ABS(@v)-@l+@l%12 AS varchar(20))+'"'
END
```

would do the trick, To be called like `dbo.ftinstr( floatval )`.

Maybe I can beautify it a little still ...

Comment: Tried that...CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),floor(finlength /12)) + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Floor(finlength %12))+'"' as FinishLen...Same error.

Comment: Well, it *does* work here: [sql-demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353414/foot-inch) ...

Comment: I don't mean to doubt your answer, I really appreciate you help. I guess I need to figure out how to get my numbers in the first line of your statement...'WITH tst as ( SELECT 13.7 finlength UNION ALL SELECT 123 )'.

Comment: Sorry, if I confused you - that was just a quick set-up to get some sample numbers tested. You should of course apply it on your own column. I will edit my post.

Comment: YES, This works just fine. Thanks for having patience with me. I just ran a couple of queries with it and it does great. Thanks again.